# ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: ReferenceError: io is not defined

Tags: java, sockets, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to create a chat app using Ionic2 (Angular2). I have a **Java Server** and **Ionic 2 Client**.

I get the following error:

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: ReferenceError: io is not defined

Any suggestions please?

## Client

```
import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from "@angular/http";
declare var io;
//require ('io');

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/chat/chat.html',
})

export class ChatPage {

  private socketHost: string = "http://localhost:3700";
  private messages: string[] = [];
  private zone: NgZone = null;
  private chatBox: string = null;
  private socket: any = null;

  constructor(http: Http) {
    this.messages = [];
    this.zone = new NgZone({ enableLongStackTrace: false });
    //let url = this.socketHost + "/fetch";
    let url = this.socketHost;
    http.get(url).subscribe((success) => {
      var data = success.json();
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        this.messages.push(data[i].message);
      }
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
    this.chatBox = "";


    this.socket = io(this.socketHost);
    this.socket.on("chat_message", (msg) => {
      this.zone.run(() => {
        this.messages.push(msg);
      });
    });
  }

  send(message) {
    if (message && message != "") {
      this.socket.emit("chat_message", message);
    }
    this.chatBox = "";
  }
}
```

## HTML

```
<ion-navbar *navbar>
    <ion-title>
        Chat
    </ion-title>
</ion-navbar>

<ion-content class="home">
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let message of messages">{{message}}</ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>

<ion-footer-bar>
    <ion-input>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="chatBox" placeholder="Message..." />
        <button (click)="send(chatBox)">Send</button>
    </ion-input>
</ion-footer-bar>
```

**index.html**

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

## Server

```
import com.corundumstudio.socketio.AckRequest;
import com.corundumstudio.socketio.Configuration;
import com.corundumstudio.socketio.SocketIOClient;
import com.corundumstudio.socketio.SocketIOServer;
import com.corundumstudio.socketio.listener.ConnectListener;
import com.corundumstudio.socketio.listener.DataListener;
import com.corundumstudio.socketio.listener.DisconnectListener;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.setHostname("localhost");
        config.setPort(3700);
        final SocketIOServer server = new SocketIOServer(config);
        server.addConnectListener(new ConnectListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConnect(SocketIOClient client) {
                System.out.println("onConnected");
                client.sendEvent("message", new Message("", "Welcome to the chat!"));
            }
        });
        server.addDisconnectListener(new DisconnectListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDisconnect(SocketIOClient client) {
                System.out.println("onDisconnected");
            }
        });
        server.addEventListener("send", Message.class, new DataListener<Message>() {

            @Override
            public void onData(SocketIOClient client, Message data, AckRequest ackSender) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("onSend: " + data.toString());
                server.getBroadcastOperations().sendEvent("message", data);
            }
        });
        System.out.println("Starting server...");
        server.start();
        System.out.println("Server started");

    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I add the following to `index.html`, and I don't get any errors any more:

`<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>`

But it just hangs. And in Firebug, I can see that the following request is just hanging:

> `GET http://localhost:3700/`

The following is printed in the server console:

> onConnected

When the server is not running the following request times out as expected, but when the server is running, the request does return, but with a `null` response:

```
GET http://localhost:3700/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=...LRQn9sx&sid=53081e79-81f3-4fc0-8fb7-17c8673938ca        
200 OK
        27ms
```

So it suggests that my server code or the communication between client and server is wrong I think.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In your Angular app you're listening for and emitting `chat_message`.

In your Java server you're listening for `send` and emitting `message`.

This doesn't add up, does it?

Comment: Thank you. I am looking into that now...  If I change '`send`' and '`message`' on the server to '`chat_message`' to match the client, I now get the following in the server logs: `Starting server...
Server started
onConnected
onDisconnected
onConnected` But the app still hangs with a `null` response from the server.

Comment: Hm, don't know anything about that sadly - that was the only obvious mistake I could see. Looking at the [Demo files](https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio-demo/blob/master/server/src/main/java/com/corundumstudio/socketio/demo/ChatLauncher.java) your Java code looks correct.

Comment: It seems to be partially working now.  Thank you for your help.